# How to test multiple Mount situations

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have a component which has a componentDidMount function that looks like this

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch, defferedLink } = this.props
    if (defferedLink) {
      dispatch(checkFetchAwsUpload(defferedLink))
    }
  }
```

Now I want to test both when defferedLink exists and when it doesn't exist.

So I write the following wrapper

```
const wrapper = shallow(
    <ImageComponentWrapper
      defferedLink={'1}
      dispatch={dispatch}
    />,
  )
```

And I run the following test

```
  expect(checkFetchAwsUpload).toBeCalledWith('1')
```

And the test passes!

However now i want to test the same component with a deferred link to be null and to test

```
   expect(checkFetchAwsUpload).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
```

But how do i set up the remount?